# How do I check firebase data() for null values on a geopoint field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I'm adding user geopoints and I'd like to check if snapShot.data().location.geopoint is null before pushing the data onto the array but I keep getting the following error:

```js
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'geopoint' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'geopoint' of undefined
```

Here is the actual code?

```js
query.get()
            .then(list => {
              list.forEach(snapShot => {
                let userLat = (snapShot.data().location.geopoint.latitude > 0) ? snapShot.data().location.geopoint.latitude : 0;
                let userLong = (snapShot.data().location.geopoint.longitude > 0) ? snapShot.data().location.geopoint.longitude : 0;

                console.log('use lat long', userLat, userLong);

                let distance = this.geo.distance(this.geo.point(myLat, myLong), this.geo.point(userLat, userLong));
                if (distance <= this.userSettings.distance.upper) {
                  this.userInfo.push({
                    userId: snapShot.data().userId,
                    displayName: snapShot.data().displayName,
                  });
                }
              });
            })
```

how would I check for a null value in geopoint given it's complaining about that actual null check I added:

```
            let userLat = (snapShot.data().location.geopoint.latitude > 0) ? snapShot.data().location.geopoint.latitude : 0;
```

Comment: Add ur firestore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the `snapshot.get(fieldPath)` API ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint)) and do:

```
let userLat = 0;
let userLong = 0;

if (snapShot.get("location.geopoint")) {
  userLat = snapShot.get("location.geopoint").latitude;
  userLong = snapShot.get("location.geopoint").longitude;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.